# undifined is not an object in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an autocomplete with react native. I pulled the data from the API

The following is the API list:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "error": false,
  "kecamatan": [
    {
      "id_kecamatan": "1",
      "kecamatan": "Gambir",
      "kode": "CGK12020",
      "id_kota": "1",
      "kota": "Jakarta Pusat",
      "id_provinsi": "1",
      "provinsi": "DKI Jakarta"
    },
    {
      "id_kecamatan": "2",
      "kecamatan": "Tanah Abang",
      "kode": "CGK12080",
      "id_kota": "1",
      "kota": "Jakarta Pusat",
      "id_provinsi": "1",
      "provinsi": "DKI Jakarta"
    },
]
}
```

when i get with fetch, i get into trouble ie,

> undifined is not an object in (evaluating kecamatan.filter)

here is my code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      kecamatan: [],
      query: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${API}/kecamatan/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json)
        const { results: kecamatan } = json;
        this.setState({ kecamatan });
      });
  }

  find(query) {
    if (query === '') {
      return [];
    }

    const { kecamatan } = this.state;
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
    return kecamatan.filter(kecamatan => kecamatan.kecamatan.search(regex) >= 0);
  }

  render() {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const kecamatan = this.find(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Autocomplete
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
            data={kecamatan.length === 1 && comp(query, kecamatan[0].kecamatan) ? [] : kecamatan}
            defaultValue={query}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
            placeholder="Enter Star Wars film title"
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item.kecamatan })}
              >
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.kecamatan}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}

          />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

please correct, this condition I want to find the name of the district using autocomplete, where I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems in your filter function:

You're extracting kecamatan from state incorrectly, it should be:

```
const { kecamatan } = this.state;
```

You're using the same name for the array and the item, you should use a different name inside your filter like this:

```
return kecamatan.filter(item => item.kecamatan.search(regex) >= 0);
```

Comment: nice bro , but after I replace it I get an error VirtualizedList: key is missing for the item

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch(`${API}/kecamatan/`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json)
    const { results: kecamatan } = json;
    this.setState({ kecamatan });
  });
```

}

Change `const { results: kecamatan }` to `const { kecamatan }` and then it will properly assign it to the state.

Answer (score 1):

`results` is not defined on the API response.

So when you do `const { results: kecamatan } = json;`, `kecamatan` is undefined, which you then set to state. So replace this with `const { kecamatan } = json;`

Answer (score 0):

You have `kecamatan.kecamatan.search(regex) >= 0)`

I do not think you have 2 layers of `kecamatan` as you already pulled it out of the state above?

`const { kecamatan } = this.state;`

Comment: return kecamatan.filter(kecamatan => kecamatan.title.search(regex) >= 0);

Answer (score 0):

Your `kecamatan` array is `undefined` because of the way you have set your fetch results.  `result` is not a key on the returned JSON, so you are trying to filter on `undefined`.  You want `const { kecamatan } = json;`

If your fetch does ever come back as `undefined`, you can guard your filter operation (i.e. instead of `return kecamatan.filter(result => ...`, you could do `return (kecamatan || []).filter(result => ...` (or in recent Typescript `return kecamatan?.filter(result => ...`.

Also, don't name your iterable the same as its member, you may get unexpected effects.  This is why I changed `kecamatan.filter(kecamatan =>` to `kecamatan.filter(result =>`.

Comment: undifined is not an object (evaluating query trim)

Comment: You are downvoting answers that lead you to new problems in your code. This may mean that the answers fixed the problem you posted about, and you are now having trouble with a different part of your code.

Comment: OP didn't downvote you, I did, because your answer is incorrect in this case, since the default state is already an empty array, there's no need to guard the filtering.

Comment: Look again at the fetch call.  OP is setting the state variable to a nonexistant key from the result, which would make the filtered variable `undefined`.

Comment: @Abe exactly, and your answer is not pointing at this problem at all.